# Convert input text into duration values with script on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, time-tracker

I'm setting up a sheet to help coworkers keep track of their appointments. For now the only way to get those times is to copy-paste the numbers from a different program used to track the info. The information pasted on the sheets shows the appointment lengths as X h X m (eg. 2 h 15 min).

The issue is the sheet will view this as text rather than a time value so I can't use the numbers to calculate anything. I found an onEdit script that will convert the text into the time values, however it requires me to go through and edit each cell (add or remove a space) before it will convert the text.

I've already set up a few scripts on this sheet so I'm hoping I can **replace the onEdit** script with one that can be run by clicking a button like the other scripts I have. The data will be pasted into same range so setting the range of where to convert will always match up.

[Script from other answer:](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/96144/human-readable-duration-values-on-google-spreadsheet)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var value = e.value;
  if (typeof value == 'string') {
    var match = value.match(/(\d+) ?h/i);
    var hours = match ? match[1] : 0;
    match = value.match(/(\d+) ?m/i);
    var minutes = match ? match[1] : 0;
    match = value.match(/(\d+) ?s/i);
    var seconds = match ? match[1] : 0;    
    if (hours || minutes || seconds) {
      var duration = hours/24 + minutes/1440 + seconds/86400;
      e.range.setValue(duration).setNumberFormat('[h]"h "m"m "s"s"');
    }
  }
}
```

edit: Changed my wording a bit to make it more clear that I want to replace the onEdit script.

edit 2: I've tried doing this to the script but it does not work:

```
function setDuration(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var value = sheet.getRange("C45:C80");
  if (typeof value == 'string') {
    var match = value.match(/(\d+) ?h/i);
    var hours = match ? match[1] : 0;
    match = value.match(/(\d+) ?m/i);
    var minutes = match ? match[1] : 0;
    match = value.match(/(\d+) ?s/i);
    var seconds = match ? match[1] : 0;    
    if (hours || minutes || seconds) {
      var duration = hours/24 + minutes/1440 + seconds/86400;
      range.setValue(duration).setNumberFormat('[h]"h "m"m "s"s"');
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not too familiar with how onEdit scripts work so I'm not sure how to properly convert the script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply to my comments in other post. It looks that you need to study more. I suggest you to start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices.

Comment: PS.:

1. `sheet.getRange("C45:C80")` returns a Class Range object, not a value.   
2. You might use `sheet.getRange("C45:C80").getValues()` to get the range values, but your code also have to iterate someway over them i.e by using a `for` loop or an Array method like `Array.prototype.map`. The best practices recommends to avoid calling Google Apps Script classes in loops, so instead of using `range.setValue(duration)` on each iteration it's better to use `range.setValues(durations)` after the loop where `durations` is an Array of Arrays containing the transformed values.

Comment: @UmaLPZ Have you been able to resolve this problem yet, or are you still looking for help?